# Does returning null in a component prevents child components from rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `LoadingProvider` where I set the state of my `Loading` component to false and when needed to true. I want to show my `Loading` component only when the state of loading equals to true.

All my `providers`, `router` and `app` `components` are loaded in my `root.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "material-ui-pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";

import App from "./App";
import { DeleteDialogProvider } from "/hocs/withDeleteDialog";
import { WarningDialogProvider } from "/hocs/withWarningDialog";
import { LoadingProvider } from "/hocs/withLoading";

import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { StateProvider } from "/hocs/withState";
import { I18nProvider } from "/hocs/withI18n";

const theme = createMuiTheme({});

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
          <I18nProvider>
            <DeleteDialogProvider>
              <WarningDialogProvider>
                <StateProvider>
                  <Router>
                    <LoadingProvider>
                      <App />
                    </LoadingProvider>
                  </Router>
                </StateProvider>
              </WarningDialogProvider>
            </DeleteDialogProvider>
          </I18nProvider>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;
```

My other providers don't block any other components from rendering. But when I add the `LoadingProvider` in `root.js` and check the console with the `React Developer Tools` I see it doesn't load/render the components that comes after my `LoadingProvider` component. The problem is that I don't know why it doesn't render any other components.

This is my `withLoading` file where I define the `LoadingProvider`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Loading from "/components/Loading";

const LoadingContext = React.createContext();

export class LoadingProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loading: false
        };
    }

    setLoadingContext = e => {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <LoadingContext.Provider value={this.setLoadingContext}>
                <Loading
                    loading={this.state.loading}
                />
            </LoadingContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export const withLoading = Component => props => (
    <LoadingContext.Consumer>
        {setLoadingContext => (
            <Component {...props} setLoadingContext={setLoadingContext} />
        )}
    </LoadingContext.Consumer>
)
```

And this is my `Loading.js` file where I define my `Loading` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

class Loading extends Component {
    render() {

        const loading = this.props;

        // TODO: fix weird repetitive loading prop
        if (!loading.loading) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (
                <CircularProgress />
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Loading;
```

I guess it has something to do with returning null when loading is false. But when I comment that rule of code out it says:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Loading(...): Nothing was returned from
>   render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to
>   render nothing, return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is primarily because in your `LoadingProvider` you are **not using `props.children`**.

```
<LoadingContext.Provider value={this.setLoadingContext}>
  <Loading
    loading={this.state.loading}
  />
  {this.props.children} // add this
</LoadingContext.Provider>
```

Take note that `null` [don't render anything](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored).

Comment: I am not using JSX

Comment: Ultimately, [every return of a component is a react element](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) and JSX produces react elements.

Comment: So because I am returning `null` it doesn't render the other components that comes after this one?

Comment: Cause your `LoadingProvider` doesn't have `{props.children}` only `Loading`

Answer (score 1):

Your `<App/>` is passed to LoadingProvider in its `children` property. But LoadingProvider doesn't do anything with its children, so nothing happens.

So return `this.props.children` when you want them to render.